# An ordinal number α which satisfies $2^\alpha=\alpha$

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

How to prove that if an ordinal number $\alpha$ satisfies $2^\alpha=\alpha$ and $\alpha\gt\omega$ then $\alpha$ is an epsilon number, i.e., $\omega^\alpha=\alpha$. I found this question on *A Book of Set Theory* written by Charles C. Pinter. I have absolutely no idea about it. Can someone help me?

---

In fact the original question is: Prove that $α$ ($α>ω$) is an epsilon number if and only if $2^α=α$. One way is just straightforward. But for the other way, my attempt is let $α=ωγ$. (Indeed, $α$ should be a limit ordinal.) Then it is easy to get that $2^{ωγ}=ωγ$, which implies that $ω^γ=ωγ$. Then it is easy to get that $2^{ωγ}=ωγ$, which implies that $ω^γ=ωγ$. Then let $γ=ω+$. (I will omit the proof that $γ>ω$.) From $ω^γ=ωγ$ it follows that: $$ω(ω+)=ω^{ω+}=(ω^ω)(ω^)=(ω^{1+ω}) \cdot (ω^)=ω \cdot ω^{ω+}.$$
Then from $ω(ω+)=ω \cdot ω^{ω+}$ we have $ω+=ω^{ω+}$, which means $γ=ω+$ is an epsilon number; finally $α=ωγ$ is an epsilon number. Is there any mistake?

Comment: Your attempt seems correct.

Answer (score 4):

**Twice edited answer:**

Yes, your attempt works. Here it is in more detail (and I mark the answer as commutity wiki).

First we divide $\alpha$ by $\omega$ to get $\alpha = \omega\gamma + n$ for some uniquely determined ordinals $\gamma$ and $n$ with $n<\omega$. Then $\alpha = 2^\alpha = 2^{\omega\gamma}2^n = (2^\omega)^\gamma 2^n = \omega^\gamma 2^n$. Since $\alpha>\omega$ we must have $\gamma>0$ and we see that $\alpha$ must be a limit ordinal, so $n$ must be $0$. We conclude that $\alpha = \omega\gamma = \omega^\gamma$.

Could we have $\gamma<\omega$? Note that $2^{\omega^{n+1}} = \omega^{\omega^n}$ for $n<\omega$ (by induction on $n$), so that cannot happen. But then we can again divide by $\omega$ to get $\gamma=\omega\beta+m$ with $\beta>0$ and $m<\omega$. Thus $\alpha=\omega\gamma = \omega^2\beta + \omega m$ with $\beta>0$. Hence $\omega + \alpha = \alpha$, and this is the key.

Now it is smooth sailing: $\omega\alpha = \omega 2^\alpha = 2^\omega 2^\alpha = 2^{\omega + \alpha} = 2^\alpha = \alpha$. And finally, $\omega^\alpha = (2^\omega)^\alpha = 2^{\omega\alpha} = 2^\alpha = \alpha$.

Comment: $2^{\omega^2}$ is not $\omega^2$. It is equal to $\omega^\omega$.

Comment: Sorry about the previous answer, which was indeed wrong.

Comment: @AndrewArmstrong I've edited slightly to explain this part. In this end, this argument is very similar to your own, that starts with $\alpha=\omega\gamma+n$ and concluding $n=0$. Of course, we get the CNF by repeatedly dividing by $\omega$.

Comment: @AndrewArmstrong your original argument is basically right, whereas my answers have been repeatedly wrong (sorry about that), so I've replaced my answer with an elaborated version of your sketch, and marked the answer community wiki.

Comment: Ulrik Buchholtz:Very thanks for your patient!Hope we can meet on other time.